# Find and replace value in column with unique identifier in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**
I have a file with two sheets (let's call them `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`).

In `Sheet1`, I have column A with unique identifiers and column B with some text.

Sample data from `Sheet1`:

A | B

1 | Apple

2 | Orange

3 | Lemon

4 | Pepper

In `Sheet2`, I have column A with the same unique identifiers and column B with different text.

Sample data from `Sheet2`:

A | B

1 | Hello

2 | How

3 | Are

4 | You

**Problem:**
I would like to have a vba code that takes one identifier from column A at a time from `Sheet2`, finds it in `Sheet1` and overwrites (replace) the text in `Sheet1` with the text from `Sheet2`.

**Code:**
I have found this code which partly works for me but instead of replacing the text in column B in `Sheet1`, it replaces the identifiers in column A in `Sheet1` with the text from `Sheet2`.

```
Sub multiFindandReplace()

Dim myList, myRange

Set myList = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B10")
'two column range with find/replace pairs
Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10")
'range to be searched and replace

For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
    myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
Next cel

End Sub
```

**Question:**
*I understand why it is doing it but how can I change it to replace the text instead of the identifier? Basically, I want `Sheet1` to look like `Sheet2` in the end but `Sheet1` has more rows than `Sheet2` and therefore, the rows are not in the same order and not all rows will need to be updated (which is why I need the 'find and replace'). Ideally this code would be triggered whenever a cell is changed in column B.*

I am also open to other code ideas or additions!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Match` to find the corresponding row on sheet1:

```
Sub multiFindandReplace()

    Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range, rw As Range, m

    Set myList = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B10")
    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10")

    For Each rw In myList.Rows
        'Find match on sheet1
        m = Application.Match(rw.Cells(1).Value, myRange.Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'Got a match: replace in ColB
            myRange.Cells(m, 2).Value = rw.Cells(2).Value
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub
```

EDIT: if calling from an event handler you must disable events before making any sheet updates, or you can get trapped in an endless loop

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    On Error Goto haveError
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B$2:$B$10")) Is Nothing Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        multiFindandReplace 'name of my macro 
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If 
    Exit Sub
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! thank you. To get this code to run only when cells in column B change, would it work if I add a `Worksheet_Change` code around it with a specific range (I was thinking `If Not Intersect([B2:B10], Target) Is Nothing Then` but I am not proficient with this type of code). Could you help me with this too?

Comment: Column B in which sheet?

Comment: Ultimately, I would like to have this code work both ways (I am assuming I will have to write two individual sub codes for that?) but this time I was talking about Sheet2.

Comment: I think I got it. I added a simple call mymacro code to it and it seems to work as expected. the code I added is: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B$2:$B$10")) Is Nothing Then
        Call multiFindandReplace 'name of my macro
    End If
End Sub`. So my last question was, can I just copy this code and edit the Sheets so it also works the other way around?

Comment: I tried adding the same code to Sheet1 (and switching the sheet names) but now it just gives me an error ('Out of stack space', number 28) and then excel just freezes. Why can't I just copy it?

Comment: When triggering code from an event handler, and that code is going to update the worksheet, which would again trigger the event handler (and so on and on) you should use `Application.EnableEvents = False` before you make any changes (then set back to `True` when done)

Comment: I understand what this code does but I am unsure on where exactly it would go in my code. would it be in the beginning & end of the actual code or of the `worksheet_change` code?

Comment: this works perfectly! Thank you very much for the fast help :)